# Partial content match in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to run a partial string match in my excel but facing to some issue to achieve it.

This is my source sheet (Spreadsheet1) which contains the master data

[image]

Below is my target Sheet (Spreadsheet2)

[image]

Now what I'm trying to do is have a partial search on `Column1` for the value from `Sheet2` and if found any then it should return the value of `Column2` and populate on `Value` column in Sheet2.

Below are the formulas I attempted so far but id didn't work.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))    

=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH("*"&A2&"*",Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an easier way to do this

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B, 
       MATCH(TRUE, 
             NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A2, Sheet1!A:A))),
       0))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

What this does is try to find the substring in the Range in `A` and return `TRUE` if it does, `FALSE` if not.
Then, on that resulting range of `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`'s we try to match the first row containing TRUE and use that to look up in column `B`

Comment: can you explain what does A7 points here? Is `$B$2:$B$5` point to source range and `$A$2:$A$5` point to target ?

Comment: getting all `#N/A`. I think A7 has to be replaced with A2 ?

Comment: No luck! :( Still getting `#N/A`

Comment: Did you conform the formula with ctrl+shift+enter?

Comment: Sorry forgot to do that. Its working perfectly! Thanks man! :)